# What information is available to an application about its launch? Can it detect that it was launched from Java?

Tags: java, windows, process, launch

When an application is launched in Windows what kind of information does it have available about it's launch? (working directory? parent process? Shortcut? icon click?)

If I launch an application from java using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("app.exe");
```

Can the application determine that it was launched from a java process?

Is there a way to make it look like a user had pressed a shortcut icon in the start menu to launch the app? (is this info even available to the application?)

I'm talking about the standard .exe executable applications in Windows.

Comment: Your question goes from very broad to less broad, but still I wonder: do you have reasons to believe it can? Do you have any specific *problem* you want to have solved? Or don't you just feel like browsing through the [process and thread API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684852(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for the link GolezTrol, I both have a problem where I'd like to somehow launch an app from Java and make it look like a user had clicked on a shortcut icon, but also want to understand how process launching in Windows works.

Comment: What does "make it look like a user had clicked on a shortcut icon" mean?

Comment: Haha SLaks, I have no idea myself, hence the broad part of the question.

Comment: Well, to rough for an actual answer, but there is the [PROCESSENTRY32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) structure, which contains a parent process. If you get that for your own application, you can then use other functions to get information about the parent process. I don't think there is an `isThisJava(processId)` function, so it may not be easy, but still, I think it should be possible, once you've found the parent process id.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and in general for being patient with my ignorance. So the child process will have access to the parent process Id. When a user double clicks an .exe file, what get's assigned as the parent id? is any other info available about the launch context?

Comment: The parent ID for a double-clicked executable is Explorer.  Other information available to the process includes the contents of the [STARTUPINFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); it is likely that Java and Explorer fill in this structure rather differently, particularly when a shortcut is involved; this is the more likely cause than the parent ID.

Comment: I suggest you start by writing a program that lists the contents of the STARTUPINFO it was given - see [GetStartupInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - and compare launching it via Java with launching it via a shortcut in Explorer.  Then write a simple C program that calls CreateProcess to launch the application you're actually interested in, and use trial and error to figure out what STARTUPINFO settings affects its behaviour (if any).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Harry, I will follow your advice